# Upgraded MB/CPU/RAM, video players now have sync problems

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, sync, upgrade

A month or so ago I upgraded the CPU, motherboard and RAM of my PC (from an i5-2500K to an i7-9700K). Windows 10 seemed to handle this change very well without having to reinstall (besides having to re-register it). Everything seems to work fine...

Except for one thing. Since the upgrade, basically all video players in Windows present a problem with most video content: As time passes, the video and audio get out of sync. Often this happens within a minute. This includes YouTube and Twitch, running on a browser, and Media Player Classic (which presents this problem the worst.) I had been using this PC with the i5 for over five years and never had any such problem. The problem started immediately happening after the hardware upgrade. This problem means that I pretty much cannot watch videos on this PC. (YouTube is bearable because pausing and resuming re-syncs the audio and video, although it can be annoying. When Media Player Classic gets out of sync, nothing seems to help, other than closing and restarting it.)

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this and how it could be fixed? Could perhaps resetting Windows (from Settings > Update&Security > Recovery > Reset this PC) maybe fix the problem? (It's my understanding that while this preserves user files, it will uninstall all programs, so it's not something that I'm extremely eager to do. But I will, if it will fix the problem.) Maybe there's some other driver I could try uninstalling and reinstalling first?

Comment: Are your videos all on-line? Have you checked your network performance? What happens with local content?

Comment: I'd start simple. Since you upgraded quite a few parts, did you install the latest drivers for your components and firmware for your motherboard? Start with that, especially graphics/display driver.

Comment: Coincidentally, Windows had yesterday a major update which, for some reason, caused the Asus updater software to also want to update things, including the sound driver. Due to the random nature of these things I'm still not keeping my hopes too high, but according to a quick testing the problem _might_ have been solved. (YouTube doesn't seem to go out of sync anymore, and the exact same video that caused MPC to go quickly out of sync seems to work fine now.) Perhaps this sound driver update did fix the problem. But only time will tell.

Comment: I was right to not get my hopes up. The problem persists after all, exactly like before. I don't know why for a while it seemed to have been gone. Now it's happening again.

Comment: I tried clean-installing the graphics and sound drivers (using the GeForce Experience software). That seemed to fix the problem for a couple of days, but then it just came back. Now, after another restart of the system, it's again working fine. It appears that the problem is intermittent. It seems that for some reason sometimes it just decides to start happening, and will continue to do so until the computer is restarted (and sometimes even immediately after that). Needless to say, this is highly annoying.

Comment: So nobody has any idea? Figured as much...